# How could humans survive on Mars for 365 days?

Tags: humans, planets

If somehow humans were stuck on Mars and had to survive 365 days, whats materials would they need? If a spaceship had a fuel leakage on the way to planet (haven't figured out the name yet) and landed on Mars due to lack of fuel, what would they have to have to survive 365 days exactly?

Comment: how many humans? what expertise? what kind of ship? what cargo if any?

Comment: are you asking for a duplicate plot of The Martian?

Comment: Assuming that they're going to a distant planet, then they'll probably have sufficient materiel to keep themselves alive for a year (with contemporary tech). A much bigger question is why did they land on Mars? A spacecraft isn't an aircraft - it won't crash due to lack of fuel, and it's hard to see any way in which Mars is much more hospitable to an unprepared group than space. And if you're awaiting rescue, that would be more easily effected from space (no need to escape Mars' gravity) than from the surface.

Comment: ...ok so I can see this needing more detail perhaps, but how exactly is it off topic?

Comment: There are quite a selection of questions regarding colonizing Mars on this site, they might have more information for you. You might also want to consider checking the Mars One Project, and other Nasa projects, or perhaps even the research being done towards this goal.

Comment: And my above comment ignores one key factor: why would they need anything more than they already have? Mars is the closest planet. So unless whatever affected their fuel also affected their cargo, then they should already have everything they need to survive in the vacuum of space. Surviving on a planet with next to no breathable air shouldn't be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

Mars is not hazardous place so a shelter with basic life support system is enough. Solar panels would give them the electricity. There is probably spares for if some of the components were to break. They need then food for a year and some water, because they can recycle but it is not 100%. There is no means of producing food in Mars yet, so it is a must have.

Thus it might be that some of the broken components of life support system need to be improvised if there were no spares. Maintaining that system is the key. If they fail everyone dies when the oxygen runs out and the water cannot be recycled. Life in Mars is fairly stable, if the system works, otherwise it means certain death.

Comment: Given that it could get as low as -55oC I think that would provide enough of an environmental hazard

Comment: Yes, but that is not too much of an issue thanks to the insulation and some heating by life support system. The space suits and the shelter from spaceship manage that one easily.

Answer (score 2):

They need food, water and breathable air. If they don't have enough in storage then they need to create or recycle it. If it wasn't a planed mission then it is unlikely they would have the stuff they need to do so just lying around.

The could try growing seeds into crops using human faeces mixed with Mars dust for nutrients, and urine for water, but it would probably fail.

They could use a purifier to convert their pee into drinkable water, but they still need a ton of water because they are losing it to evaporation.